# Selecting a default value on select box options with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have read several posts on this issue and the solutions given on this site don't seem to work for me. I have a select box with several options and I need a default value to be show to the user. Currently no option is selected. What could be wrong with this code.

HTML

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" name="collegeTranscripts1" id="collegeTranscripts1" data-ng-  model='transcriptCAdata.typeAccepted' data-ng-options='option.value as option.name for option in typeOptions1'></select>
```

JS

```
$scope.typeOptions1 = [
            { name: 'Please Select', value: 'selected' },
            { name: 'Official', value: 'OFFICIAL' },
            { name: 'Unofficial', value: 'UNOFFICIAL' },
            { name: 'None', value: 'NONE' }
        ];

        $scope.form = {type : $scope.typeOptions1[0].value};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems that I see in your code:

1. The HTML attribute `data-ng-model` is separated, it looks like this: `data-ng-   model='transcriptCAdata.typeAccepted'`.
2. Another is that in your model, you are using a scope attribute `transcriptCAdata.typeAccepted` but you didn't declare it in your controller. What I see in your controller though is `$scope.form = {type : $scope.typeOptions1[0].value};`.

You simply have to change your `data-ng-model` to `data-ng-model="form.type"`.

## DEMO

```js
angular.module('app', [])

  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.typeOptions1 = [
            { name: 'Please Select', value: 'selected' },
            { name: 'Official', value: 'OFFICIAL' },
            { name: 'Unofficial', value: 'UNOFFICIAL' },
            { name: 'None', value: 'NONE' }
        ];

    $scope.form = {type : $scope.typeOptions1[1].value};
  });
```

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <select class="form-control input-sm" name="collegeTranscripts1"
          id="collegeTranscripts1" data-ng-model='form.type' 
          data-ng-options='option.value as option.name for option in typeOptions1'>
  </select>
  
  {{form.type}}
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

## *UPDATE:*

I have copied the **[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/8J4vG7lbwWy3vMxXMX4S?p=preview)** you have provided and revised it, since it had problems in it.

Comment: the ng-model has to be ng-model='transcriptCAdata.typeAccepted'

Comment: why wouldnt this work: $scope.transcriptCAdata = {typeAccepted : $scope.typeOptions1[0].value};

Comment: how about: $scope.transcriptCAdata = {typeAccepted : $scope.typeOptions1 = 'selected'};

Comment: how about you change it to  `$scope.transcriptCAdata = {typeAccepted : $scope.typeOptions1[1].value};`  and see if the selected value is Official.

Comment: It doesnt select any options that way either

Comment: Can you replicate the problem in a [plunker](http://plnkr.co)? It would be much easier to trace the problem.